# Norm inequality for the $1$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

I am currently working on some kind of proof and I asked myself if there is somehow some geometric argument/inequality I am possibly unware of that shows the following statement:

Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with only positive entries, $\lambda > 0$ and let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ be a positive matrix in the sense of Perron-Frobenius theory (not necessarily positive definite!), i.e., all entries are positive. Can one show that
$$\lambda \lVert x \rVert_1 + \lVert A x \lVert_1 \geq \lambda \lVert A \rVert_{1 \to 1} \cdot \lVert x \lVert_1?$$
Here, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{1 \to 1}$ denotes the operator norm with respect to the $1$-norm on $\mathbb R^n$/$\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: And why do you think this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general. Choose $A$ such that $\left\|A\right\|_{1\to 1} > 1$ then for $\lambda > \frac{\left\|A\right\|_{1\to 1}}{\left\|A\right\|_{1\to 1} - 1} > 0$ and $x\neq 0$,

$$\lambda \left\|x\right\|_1 + \left\|Ax\right\|_1 \le \left(\lambda + \left\|A\right\|_{1\to 1}\right) \left\|x\right\|_1 < \lambda \left\|A\right\|_{1\to 1} \left\|x\right\|_1$$